# Excel formula - finding dynamic ranges in column that is surrounded by 0-values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking at stock-data at 1 minute resolution in a spreadsheet. I have been stuck at this problem for a few days now, testing different methods.

What I am doing is that I have formulas dictating entries and sells based on the stock-data, and then I have 2 existing formulas that finds the highest/lowest price the stock reached inbetween entry and sell minutes. So far, so good, now I need to find at which minute (= row) this highest and lowest price occurred.
I have some versions that I tested that works when I have only 1 entry and sell, but it gets messed up when I have several entries and sells.
[image]

Added a screenshot for sample data.
This data should be read from BOTTOM and UP.
First column is = 1 if a trade is active.
Second column keeps track of the highest value that has occurred for the active trade and is reset for next entry.
Third column keeps track of the lowest value that has occurred for the active trade and is reset for the next entry.

I need help with formulas in column 4-5 to find WHEN the highest value occurred in the active trades and the lowest value respectively.

There could be cases where I have more than 2 entries as well.
Current formula in column 4:
=IF(AND(B4>B5,B3<=B4),%%time of row from other cell here%%,MISSING())
as you can see, for the 2nd entry I have 2 cases when this formula gives "true", which is faulty. Only the one showing as 09:54 should be there.

The formula for column 5 is very bad, it's written with MIN-if combo but I know this won't work in many cases, so I omit it here.

Edit:

| Time | 1=In trade | Highest value in trade so far | Lowest value in trade so far | High minute | Low Minute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-12 10:01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 10:00 | 1 | 4,13 | 3,5 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:59 | 1 | 4,13 | 3,9003 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:58 | 1 | 4,13 | 3,9003 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:57 | 1 | 4,13 | 3,9003 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:56 | 1 | 4,13 | 3,9003 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:55 | 1 | 4,13 | 3,9003 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:54 | 1 | 4,13 | 3,94 | 09:54:00 | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:53 | 1 | 4,09 | 3,94 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:52 | 1 | 4,09 | 3,94 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:51 | 1 | 4,09 | 3,94 | 09:51:00 | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:50 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:49 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:48 | 1 | 4,03 | 3,88 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:47 | 1 | 4,03 | 3,88 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:46 | 1 | 4,03 | 3,88 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:45 | 1 | 4,03 | 3,88 | 09:45:00 | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:44 | 1 | 4,01 | 3,88 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |
| 2020-05-12 09:43 | 1 | 3,98 | 3,88 | #SAKNAS! | 09:43:00 |
| 2020-05-12 09:42 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #SAKNAS! | #SAKNAS! |

Comment: Have you considered using MAXIFS()? Also it's advisable to post data as data not as a picture. You could use   https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# for that. Please include the time column.

Comment: Hi, Added table with data instead, and included time column. 

Yes, I've tried a few variations, but problem with MAXIFS, MINIFS etc is which range should I use for the formula, that will work for any number of entries?

The MAXIF should only use the data for each trade, and be reset for the next entry.

Comment: To clarify:
The MAXIF should only use the data for each trade, and be reset for the next trade.
I was thinking a formula that finds the dynamic range between the 0-values in column 2/"in trade" and use this as a range input to MAXIFS and MINIFS for the two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maxby a bit overkill, but how about:

```
=LET(range,A2:C21,
     time,INDEX(range,,1),
     trade,INDEX(range,,2),
     value,INDEX(range,,3),
     DROP(REDUCE(0,trade,
          LAMBDA(x,y,
          VSTACK(x,
                 IF(y=0,
                    "",
                    LET(sq,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(trade)),
                        start,XLOOKUP(1,(trade=0)*(sq+1<=ROW(y)),sq+2,"",0,-1),
                        end,XMATCH(1,(INDEX(trade,sq)=0)*(sq+1>=ROW(y))),
                        sqsingle,SEQUENCE(1+end-start,,start-1),
                        singlevalue,INDEX(value,sqsingle),
                        singlemax,XLOOKUP(MAX(singlevalue),singlevalue,sqsingle,,0,-1),
                        INDEX(time,singlemax)))))),
     1))
```

It isolates the range of a single trade and looks for the position of the max value in that range (bottom to top) and returns the (date &) time.

[image]

alternative solution without REDUCE() to be used in row 2 and needs dragged down:

```
=LET(range,$A$2:$C$21,
     time,INDEX(range,,1),
     trade,INDEX(range,,2),
     value,INDEX(range,,3),
     start,XLOOKUP(0,B$2:B2,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B$2:B2))+1,,0,-1),
     end,XLOOKUP(1,(trade=0)*(ROW(trade)>=ROW()),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(trade))-1),
     sqsingle,SEQUENCE(1+end-start,,start),
     singlevalue,INDEX(value,sqsingle),
     singlemax,XLOOKUP(MAX(singlevalue),singlevalue,sqsingle,,0,-1),
     IF(B2=0,"",INDEX(time,singlemax)))
```

And for MIN value:

```
=LET(range,$A$2:$D$21,
     time,INDEX(range,,1),
     trade,INDEX(range,,2),
     value,INDEX(range,,4),
     start,XLOOKUP(0,B$2:B2,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B$2:B2))+1,,0,-1),
     end,XLOOKUP(1,(trade=0)*(ROW(trade)>=ROW()),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(trade))-1),
     sqsingle,SEQUENCE(1+end-start,,start),
     singlevalue,INDEX(value,sqsingle),
     singlemax,XLOOKUP(MIN(singlevalue),singlevalue,sqsingle,,0,-1),
     IF(B2=0,"",INDEX(time,singlemax)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I was trying to convert this to Swedish formula-syntax, but my excel-version apparently does not support some of the functions used, e.g. the "reduce"-function. My version is an office 365 one  (computer from work) but does not recognize this function! 

I am glad that you did understand my problem at least. Your picture shows that your formula should work. 

VBA is also possible solution if it is easier.

Comment: This site can be helpful for translating formulas https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/ though I think this is a version thing. REDUCE was introduced from a certain version of Office 365. It may not've been released yet by your company.

Comment: Yes most likely since all the functions; drop, reduce, lambda, vstack are not recognized. Actually there is no swedish translation for them either, they are supposed to be used with the same function-name for swedish locale as well. Accordingly to your link and the translator-add-in I tested, and microsoft support pages in swedish regarding the specific functions. 

Do you think there is another way to solve this by using older functions or VBA? I already am running VBA looping through some of this data - saving it to other worksheets when I loop through other stocks.

Comment: I posted an alterative solution which - I think - would have all functions available.

Comment: Perfect, I tested it and it works brilliantly! 
Now I also need a similar one that gives the MIN value as well, for the next column, the values in D. I tried editing your code by expanding to D-column, changing value to column 4 and then just exchanging "max" to "min", but it does not behave correctly. It gives the wrong time.

Comment: See edit (also found a minor mistake in the previous formula)